# Declaring literal strings

Tags: c++, string

When I want to write a literal string in Python, I use `r` before the string (or `@` in C#):

```
in [1]: print r'\no esca\pe ch\ara\cters'
out [1]: \no esca\pe ch\ara\cters
```

In straight c++ I can use `R`, but in the Arduino IDE, this throws the following error:

```
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println(R"\no esca\pe ch\ara\cters");

<output> invalid character '\'in raw string delimiter
```

So how do I do the same in Arduino c++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raw strings in C++11 must have parens within the quotes in order to allow for a custom delimiter. Since your string lacks those parens, it is not valid.

```
Serial.println(R"(\no esca\pe ch\ara\cters)");
```